# JQuery: select an HTML table that contain a given element

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following HTML

```
<table id = "mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Hiring Manager</th>
    <td><textarea id = "textComments" cols = "15"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From the above markup, I'd like to append the following row

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>
       <span class = "CharCounter">
           <span id="lblCharCounter">Label</span>
           characters (500 max)
       </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to select the table, from the **textarea**.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add another row inside of the table, find the textarea, and slowly work your way until you get to the point you want. To go back an element, simply use .parent() again.

```
$('#textComments').parent().parent().after('
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>
         <span class = "CharCounter">
           <span id="lblCharCounter">Label</span>
           characters (500 max)
         </span>
      </td>
   </tr>'
);
```

Comment: The way to navigate from lower level to upper level is by using parent function?

Comment: If that is the field that you want and it is near the parent then yes. there are other ways too but this is standard.