# knowing an element's id, how to find an other element located in the same table?

Tags: jquery

Earlier I asked the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689138/jquery-select-an-html-table-that-contain-a-given-element) on how to add a HTML table row using JQuery, knowing the id on an element inside a table cell.

So, after adding the new row, the table look like this now:

```
<table id = "mytable">
  <tr>
     <th>Hiring Manager</th>
     <td><textarea id = "textComments" cols = "15"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>
        <span class = "CharCounter">
           <span id="lblCharCounter">Label</span>
           characters (500 max)
        </span>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

I want to know, knowing the id of the first element (i.e. **textComment**), how can I select the second element located in the row below, (i.e. **lblCharCounter**)?

Thank for helping

Comment: Yes, however, why not just get a reference to it before you append it? It has an ID that you specifically gave it in your previous question, there's no reason not to select it by that id. `$("#lblCharCounter")`

Comment: The problem is that I count to use every where there is a text area. I want the selection to be related to the control a textarea. Let's say someone press a key, I want to control which label will be selected.

Comment: It won't work unless you use a class rather than an ID, ID's must be unique. However, you still should instead store a reference to it when you append it with the code from your previous question rather than appending then trying to navigate to it.

Comment: make sense. Can u write code, so I have an idea about what you are saying? How about searching by element type, i.e. span?

Comment: it would be something like this: http://pastebin.com/cAxuZWsS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably go with:

```
$('#textComment').closest('table').find('.CharCounter')
```

or (to get that specific sub-`span`)

```
$('#textComment').closest('table').find('.CharCounter').children()
```

or something similar -- It's easiest if you assign a unique class, in addition to the ID, to that element you want to locate.

http://api.jquery.com/closest

http://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: beat me to it. `$.fn.closest` and `$.fn.find` combined with semantic class names are especially good because they do not break as easily when your html changes.

Comment: In the children function I added children('[id*="lblCharCounter"]'), and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $area1 = $("#textComments");
```

Then use:

```
$area1.parent().parent().next().find('#lblCharCounter")
```

Comment: this selects the next td (there isn't one) so you'll end up with 0 elements selected.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, missed that.